# Open a new cmd console on Windows 2012 Server core after closing the last one?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, windows-command-prompt, windows-server-core

On my new test server, which is a Windows Server 2012 core server, I've closed the only open cmd console with the `exit` command.

How do I open another prompt now? Am I going to be forced to reboot the machine?

Comment: press windows key, enter "cmd", wait, press return, finish

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[From the Technet article titled *Manage a Server Core Server*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574205.aspx):

> If you close all command prompt windows and want to open a new Command
>   Prompt window, press CTRL+ALT+DELETE, click Start Task Manager, click
>   More Details, click File, click Run, and then type cmd.exe.
>   Alternatively, you can log off and log back on.

Comment: If you've remoted into the machine use Ctrl + Alt + End instead of Ctrl + Alt + Del.

Comment: And if you remoted into machine 1 and *from there* remoted into the Server Core machine 2, use the on-screen-keyboard on machine 1 to press Ctrl + Alt +End.

Comment: @Heinzi gave a very good answer too as, in some conditions, we bounce from one machine to another.

Answer (score 42):

You can also press the following keys simultaneously to bring up the Task Manager - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> Then, [as xstnc said](https://serverfault.com/a/512234), File -> Run New Task -> cmd/powershell

Comment: Why the down vote? The keyboard shortcut is correct.

Comment: THIS.  This is what works if you are on remote desktop.

Comment: This is what works for me on Macbook  2020

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to do this as a comment, because this is mostly a straight up copy and paste. But I'm a n00b so must post as an answer. I just added a hint for those doing RDP

If you close all command prompt windows and want to open a new Command Prompt window, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>.

If you are using RDP to connect remotely, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>.

Next click Start Task Manager, click More Details, click File, click Run, and then type cmd.exe. Alternatively, you can log off and log back on.

Answer (score 4):

I was just in that situation to get that prompt over RDP and using a boot camp MacbookAir with reduced keyboard and want to share.

in this case it is:

```
fn+ctrl+alt + (->) (Arrow right key)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to open the ServerManager, click on Tools and then select Windows PowerShell, type cmd and there you go....

Comment: And how does one open ServerManager on core, when all other windows are closed?